# How to get instances in all private fields of an object?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I would like to use reflection to investigate the private fields of an object as well as get the values in those fields but I am having difficult finding the syntax for it.

For example, an object has 6 private fields, my assumption is that I could fetch their FieldInfo with something like

```
myObject.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

but no dice - the call returns an array of 0.

Whats the correct syntax to access fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static
```

Comment: Ahh, its the Instance that I was missing

Comment: Just added the static bit in case you needed that too :)

Answer (score 4):

You've overridden the default flags, so you need to add `Instance` back in...

```
myObject.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also add **BindingFlags.Instance**

```
myObject.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to retrieve both fields and values:

```
from field in myObject.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
select new
{
    Field = field,
    Value = field.GetValue(myObject)
};
```